# Android : Custom List view Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I made a custom layout for a list view. The layout has 2 text views , one button and one image view. When i inflate the layout on my listview it works fine , but when i swipe up and down the list view , i check my log cat and find that the memory is leaking , i don't know what the problem is :

here is the logcat :

06-27 20:37:29.321: D/dalvikvm(9034): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1749K, 16% free 15831K/18723K, paused 1ms+10ms

06-27 20:37:32.451: D/dalvikvm(9034): GC_CONCURRENT freed 175K, 7% free 20124K/21475K, paused 2ms+18ms

06-27 20:37:35.591: D/dalvikvm(9034): GC_CONCURRENT freed 45K, 5% free 25948K/27171K, paused 2ms+12ms

my code :

```
l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,songs);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

CustomAdapter class :

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context c;
    LayoutInflater li;
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ImageView i;
    TextView t1,t2;
    Button b;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> resource)
    {
        super(context,R.id.textView1, resource);
        c = context;
        names = resource;           
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview, null);

        i = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        t1.setText(songs.get(position));
        t2.setText(songs.get(position));

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I replaced the above code with this , but the problem is still the same .

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        pos = position;
        Log.i("in getView",Integer.toString(pos));
        //li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview, parent,false);

        i = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_filter);
        t1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        LinearLayout linearonclick = (LinearLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.LinearlayoutOnClickListView);
        b = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button_eq);

        t1.setText(names.get(position));
        t2.setText(names.get(position));

        linearonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.i("in on Click",Integer.toString(pos));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),songs.get(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You selected modd Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return customView;
    }
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387269/listview-gets-out-of-memory-exception-but-with-no-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0):

In the getView method you want to only inflate a new convertView if it is not null.  First check to see that it is not null and if it is the correct type then use it.

From the [Adapter getView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)):

> **convertView**:  The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check
>   that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If
>   it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data,
>   this method can create a new view. Heterogeneous lists can specify
>   their number of view types, so that this View is always of the right
>   type (see getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int)).